# How to Embed a YoutUbe Video with no sound in HTML5

Tags: audio, video, youtube, embed

Hello I am using HTML5 on my website. I saw a post where to embed a video with no sound, use this code, and also put it in this folder (a folder with 2 javascript files and shockwave flash object, etc, etc. 
                              
                    
                    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.

```
                <script type="text/javascript">

            var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
            var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
            swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/_Znb-uKHUZ4?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer", 
                   "ytapiplayer", "380", "245", "8", null, null, params, atts);

            function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
                ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
                ytplayer.mute();
            }
```

It seems that only works with HTML as I tried it on a normal webpage and it worked fine. So is there a way to embed a youtube video in HTML5 with no sound. And also is it posibble to embed my most recent youtube videos?

P.S. my website is www.avoktv.com

Thanks again!

UPDATE: I found this post to embed a youtube playlist and they gave this code

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="ytapiplayer">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this              video.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
ytplayer.playVideo();
ytplayer.mute();
}
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/mOLp4doE51Q&list=PL86C090F73345FED6&feature=plpp_play_all?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&allowFullScreen=true&version=3&loop=1&autohide=1",
"ytapiplayer", "100%", "380", "8", null, null, params, atts)
</script>
```

It did not work in my website which is HTML5. But it worked just when i was testing it on a blank page. And yes, I uploaded it to the website i did not test it on my local host.

For clarification: in both these spots i used the same code: One came up with this http://www.avoktv.com (you need to click the avoktv logo and then scroll down, it says something like "you need falsh 8 and javascript etc". and then here is a working example of what i want on my homepage which is html5 i think http://www.avoktv.com/aaaaa.html ;